# How do you completely purge Apache, MySQL, PHP, and phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, php5

I really need to completely purge my web server on Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried `sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin` (which hopefully removes all of them). How do I completely purge all of them?

Comment: Reinstall the OS.  If that's not an option, be specific about what you feel should be 'purged' that isn't already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you have to remove Apache and all of it's dependencies.

```
apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

and then

```
rm -rf /etc/apache2; rm -rf /etc/php5; rm -rf /var/lib/mysql; rm etc/mysql
```

And then reinstall.

If you have any issues with phpMyAdmin, try entering this into the Terminal:

```
dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Comment: do u knwo the equivalent commands in Mac?

Comment: 2nd step have correction to removing MYSQL here is the correction 
`rm -rf /etc/apache2; rm -rf /etc/php5; rm -rf /var/lib/mysql; rm -rf /etc/mysql;`
you forgot to add `-rf` and `/` into last command